# Out of memory issue while slicing scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, dask

We have sparse csr matrix and while slicing the matrix we are getting out of memory (OOM) issue.

> X[:, feature_sample]

Here `X` is of the dimension : [8000000, 138106]

`feature_sample` is a randomly generated boolean array of the shape (138106,) Ex of it : `[True True False False ......True]`

Here since column slicing is being done csc matrix is more efficient for the operation but modifying X to a csc matrix didn't help address the OOM issue.

Tried converting this to a dask array but before proceeding need to convert it back to a csr matrix for the next set of operations on X so that resulted in failure.
Looking for suggestions that can help avoid the OOM while slicing the matrix.

Comment: How big is `feature_sample`?  Most CSR/C indexing is done with an extractor matrix and matrix multiplication.

Comment: OOM isn't an obvious abbreviation.  I made a good guess, still ...

Comment: @hpaulj The feature_sample is boolean matrix of the shape (138106,) used to determine which columns from the matrix X need to be selected.

Comment: Does using `np.nonzero(feature_sample)[0]` make a difference?  i wanted an jdea of how many columns you were selecting.

Comment: X is somewhere between 100 MB and 20 TB, depending on sparsity. Maybe you're just out of memory because you ran out of memory?

Comment: @hpaulj - The number of columns we select is randomized. 
Ex of the `feature_sample` - `[True False True ............False]`                                        @CJR - We are running out of memory only while slicing the matrix. Looking for ways to optimize the indexing operation - liking maybe first chunking `X` etc.

Comment: Does the memory error give a traceback?  or just kill the process?   A traceback might give us a clue as to what it's doing at the time.  Assuming my past observation about the indexing method, it may have problems creating the `extractor` matrix.  Or it may the matrix multiplication.  I prefer not to test memory-error cases because it tends to incompacitate my computer for a while.

Comment: unfortunately no traceback, the process just gets killed.

Comment: Slicing here means copying - unless you're having a problem trying to slice out a single column, it's likely that you might not have enough memory to make the copy you want to make.